# How to set lifetime for specific domain in laravel 4.2 with redis driver?

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4, redis

My `config/session/lifetime` is `720`. I want to set lifetime to `4320` in `api.example.com` only, other domains in this project also use `720`.

Now I use:

```
Config::set('session.lifetime', 4320)
```

before api.example.com,it just makes the cookie expired in 4320 minutes,but the redis ttl is also 720*60 s, so the data stored in Session will destroy in 720 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I got it.
Just add judgment in the config/session.php like:

`'lifetime' => $_SERVER['HOST_NAME'] == 'api.example.com' ? 4320 : 720`